# domain redirects to subdomain

Tags: redirect, domain

I am facing an issue I created a subdomain , I am using hosting so I choose an auto-installer option and choose subdomain but after some time when I click on my main domain it redirects to the subdomain , I deleted subdomain but still I am facing this issue

Comment: This is probably a question for your hosting, sorry. Can you explain in more detail? You have a WordPress instance on your domain? Is it set up for multisite - was the subdomain part of the multisite instance? Have you made sure the subdomain isn't anywhere in the configuration e.g. in wp-config.php as blog or site URL, or in the configuration in the admin pages?

Comment: Flagged because problem based on cPanel like hosting problem.